# excel multiple criteria and transform horizontaly to verticaly

Tags: excel, matrix

I have unique number of items and invoices, but one invoice can have multiple items.

```
    A        B    C    D
1 Invoice  Items
2   1        10
3   2        20
4   1        30
```

idea is sort it to horizontaly via this formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$8;SMALL(IF($D$2=$A$2:$A$8;ROW($A$2:$A$8)-ROW($A$2)+1);COLUMN(A1)));"")
```

result:

```
    A      B     C    D       E     F
1 Invoice Items     Invoice  Item1 Item2
2   1      10         1        10    30
3   2      20
4   1      30
```

But my geal is setup results horizontaly:

```
    A         B
 1  Invoice   Items
 2   1        10
 3   1        30
 4   2        20
```

Is that even possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Is your goal actually to sort on Invoice first and then on Items? If so, why just not using sort on two levels using the build in option?

**Input:**

[image]

**Sort:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

It's in Dutch but you'll get the idea :)